# Using Regex in JavaScript to get an array of numbers from string including negatives and floats

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to retrieve all numbers, even negatives and decimals, from a string using JavaScript. Ideally, these numbers would be in an array.

```
Examples:
'1 2.5 5' ---> [1, 2.5, 5]
'-4.7 abcd56,23' ---> [-4.7, 56, 23]
```

Here's what I have:

```
function processUserInput() {
  let rawUserInput = document.getElementById("number-input").value;
  let negativeNumRegex = /^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/g;
  return negativeNumRegex.exec(rawUserInput);
}
```

UPDATE:
This is correct

```
/-?[.\d]+/g
```

Comment: It rarely makes sense to have an expression with anchors at both ends and the `g` flag. (It can, with an alternation, but other than that it usually doesn't.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You're right, I changed it back to the way my code actually looks. That's not the issue with my code right now, the string is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It rarely makes sense to have an expression with anchors at both ends and the `g` flag. (It can, with an alternation, but other than that it usually doesn't.)

I'd probably use something simpler: `/-?[.\d]+/g`

```js
const rex = /-?[.\d]+/g;
console.log('1 2.5 5'.match(rex));
console.log('-4.7 abcd56,23'.match(rex));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Note that that doesn't validate against things like `4..2` and such. Exercise left to the reader. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This regex:

```
/^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/g
```

Should be:

```
/-?\d+(\.\d+)?/g
```

So it can find numbers anywhere inside the string, and not from the beginning to the end of the whole string.

Next time I suggest you to test your regular expression in [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and you will see why it is failing.

Comment: That's a step in the right direction for me! However, it's only working for the first number. /-?\d+(\.\d+)?/g.exec('1 -2 3.5') is returning an array with a length of one. It works on the website you linked, but not in the console. Am I missing something?

Comment: Use match in string, not exec in regex. T.J Crowder's answer contains an example.

Comment: Ah yes, I see now. There's a lot of answers similar to this on Stack Overflow but I really needed that example from T.J. to show me how to actually use a regex once I've found the correct expression for my purposes.